# Google Sheets IMPORTXLM function removes leading zeros

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

In Google sheets I'm trying to import product prices from a website. My code works well except when there is a leading zero after the comma (like 1.09 gives 1.9). This is because the website has the decimal price written as 09 and google sheets removes this zero before my JOIN function can combine them.

`=JOIN("",IMPORTXML("https://www.ah.nl/producten/product/wi111767/ah-rucola","//div[@class='price-amount_root__Sa88q product-card-hero-price_now__zHsgu']"))`

The used functions are:

`=IMPORTXML(url, xpath_query)`
`=JOIN(delimiter, value_or_array1, [value_or_array2, ...])`

I tried formating the cell as text but this didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.ah.nl/producten/product/wi111767/ah-rucola","//div[@class='product-card-hero-price_root__Cx0SP']"),1)
```

[image]